# How can I check if a relay module is conducting electricity?

Tags: relay, power-flow-analysis

I want to know if a 5V water pump connected to a classical relay module which is connected to (SBC) ESP32s's GPIO can check if there was a failure in water pump and no electricity is flowing through the relay's isolated current site into water pump.

Comment: Realize that not all failures in the water pump will stop the current from flowing. If the pump rotor gets stuck, current might still flow while no water is being pumped. To detect current flow you will need to add an (isolated!) current sensing module.

Comment: `Code formatting` is used for source code, not emphasis. Use _italics_ for emphasis.

Comment: edited! Thanks , I'm going to check for that!

Comment: Anyway, what exactly is a "5V water pump"? Does it actually operate on 5VDC? This is for an aquarium or some such? What is a "classic relay module"? I'm assuming 5V coil but what do you have on the pump side?

Comment: it operates 3~5V USB water pump. I think it is usually used in ponds as mini-fountain. Yes the 5V relay module google shows when search for *sbc relay module*. My has 8 channels because I need it also for another devices

Comment: @Lundin a relay, soldered onto a circuit board, designed for easy integration with arduino or similar. You do *not* need the datasheet of the relay to answer this question.

Comment: @user253751 One needs to know the voltage and currents on the secondary side in order to answer how to measure that current.

Comment: @Lundin then ask how much current the water pump uses.

Comment: In this case since you have relatively small currents and 5V, you could simply connect a Schmitt trigger digital isolator directly to the secondary side. With a pull-down, maybe in combination with a RC filter, and then maybe a current limiting series resistor. That's for a digital signal "working"/"not working". To measure the current, that's another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series sense resistor and voltage monitor would sense current.

If you have enough 'headroom' to drop 0.6 v a transistor base to resistor top, emitter to resistor ground will turn the transistor on when the motor is drawing current.
Resistor = V/I
=~  0.5/ motor_current .
Using 0.5 provides slight headroom.
A capacitor across the resistor may help.
The transistor can drive an LED or other circuitry.
eg for Imotor = 200 mA R = 0.5/0.2 = 2.5 ohms.